# Tag Issue in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
//This code will print the as per the request.
Response.Write("<<<<<<<=======>>>>>>>>>>");

//In this case its not writing as per the request.
Response.Write("<<<<<<<hello======>>>>>>>>>>");
```

Here in this case its print only <<<<<<>>>>>>>>>.Means it removes the all text,associated all = symbols.

Whats this issue?I just write the text only.But not getting.

Anyone knows this..help me?

Comment: context? are you saying that the final html (from view-source, or fiddler, etc) contains `<<<<<<<=======>>>>>>>>>>` from the first, but only contains `<<<<<<>>>>>>>>>` from the second? Also: if this is html or xml (since you mention "tag"), why are you even sending `<<<<<<` etc, when that *isn't html / xml* ?

Comment: I need to read data from Sharepoint list.
This is my query 
Query="<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Po_x0020_NUm' /><Value Type='Text'>" + e.Item.Cells[0].Text + "</Value></Eq></Where>";
Here <,>tags are there.These tag is not taking in C# to retrieve.So
I check the issue..And try to write just texts inside tags.Same issue even writing the text only.

Comment: Be very careful: if you are in the habit of writing things like the `Query` above, then your site is ***full*** of XSS vulnerabilities (a major security problem).

Answer (score 6):

I believe the <hello is treated as a tag. I would recommend to use

```
Response.Write(HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("<<<<<<<hello======>>>>>>>>>>"));
```

Answer (score 3):

That *isn't html* (or xml). The `<` / `>` should be escaped to `&lt;` / `&gt;`. To avoid mistakes etc (as the contents change), best to use a utility method:

```
string s = "<<<<<<<hello======>>>>>>>>>>";
Response.Write(HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(s));
```